# Как web приложение может найти свой исходный код?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, java-ee

В качестве сервера и контейнера использую apache tomcat. Запущенное приложение должно "найти" свой исходный код и послать его по почте.
Меня интересует как можно объяснить приложению где или как искать свой код.

Comment: а чем вы war собираете?

Comment: maven. проект создан в InteliJ Idea

Answer (score 2):

Исходный код компилируется и пакуется, обычно в `jar` или `war` архив. Т.ч. приложение не сможет его найти при всем желании.

Но выход из данной ситуации несомненно есть - вы можете собрать это самое приложение вместе с исходным кодом, положив его в папку с ресурсами.

Если система сборки `maven` то добавляете плагин:

```
<build>
 <plugins>
    ...
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
 <resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/java</directory>
        <includes>
            <include> **/*.java</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

Далее в самом коде используете следующую инструкцию:

```
InputStream input = getClass()
                        .getResourceAsStream("/com/company/MySuperClass.java");
```

Comment: А если зависимости? А как же pom и структура проекта?

Comment: понятно, что там все не так тривиально. Я дал лишь направление, куда двигаться. А все дальнейшие грабли автор вопроса путь берет на себя.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете добавить вот этот плагин

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                <targetPath>WEB-INF/sources</targetPath>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

и тогда исходный код вашего проекта будет находится внутри WEB-INF/sources. Вам надо будет написать сервлет или создать jsp для доступа к нему. Либо сменить `targetPath` и переместить файлы в открытый доступ, но это не правильно с точки зрения безопасности.